# Formula Field To Return Different Data Type?

Tags: formula

Can I return two different data types in formula field based on some criteria?

Say I have a `Formula1__c` field with a **percent** return type, and `Roll_up Summary__c` field that counts all detail records wherein `Picklist__c` value = '**A**'.

There's a requirement that if `Roll_up Summary__c` > 0, a formula field with text return type named `Result__c` must be equal to **A**, while if `Roll_up Summary__c` = 0, `Result__c` must be equal to `Formula1__c`.

Please bear with me, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not return a text in both scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Formula should always return selected type.

In your case I would either: Create formula and depending on conditions return parsed values (there are functions for that eg TEXT() VALUE()) or create two formula fields each working with desired requirements.

Comment: i've tried `TEXT(Formula1__c)` but it just returns zero. Would not it get the exact value of `Formula__c`? Say its value is 100%. Isn't it possible to get it in that state?